# Digit Grouping Symbol messes with number format

Tags: c#, winforms, string-formatting

I have a WinForms application, in which I have a label, where I bind a decimal to. I have also added a .Format method to the binding. Like this:

```
// Add data binding for the lavel
Binding bindWithFormat = new Binding("Text", viewModel, nameof(viewModel.BindingNumber));
bindWithFormat .Format += viewModel.FormatAsNumber;
lblNumber.DataBindings.Add(bindWithFormat);

// Formatting function
public void FormatAsNumber(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    // The method converts only to string type. Test this using the DesiredType.
    if (e.DesiredType != typeof(string)) return;

    // Formats the value with thousand separator and zero decimals
    e.Value = String.Format("{0:N0}", e.Value);
}
```

This works fine under normal circumstances, but if I choose a particular type of Digit Grouping Symbol, it looks like this (it is supposed to show "15 000 000"):

[image: Error when formatting number]

I first thought it was when I used a blank space (`" "`) as symbol, but when I explicitly type a blank space, then it shows it as intended. However, there is another symbol I can chose in the regional settings, which looks like a space, but it causes the above formatting error when selected (unlike when I explicitly type space):

[image: "Pseudo space" symbol in regional settings]

What the heck is going on? According to [this website](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%20), the symbol is "*[no break space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)*" (U+00A0). So it is a space. But not a space. And for some reason, it seriously messes up the formatting. What to do?

**Bonus info:** After playing around some more, it seems to only affect that specific font, that I was using (it only exists in my company). If I change fonts to e.g. Segoe UI, then the problem disappears.

Comment: My crystal ball says that the 0 fell off because the string did not fit.  Use another font, one with a narrower pitch or smaller point size, and it magically seems to work again.  Hehe.

Comment: The ridicoulous thing is, that the label is fixed width (no auto size). They are all the same size. But the top one is missing 5 zeroes, while the bottom is only missing one (they are both bound to the value). Only difference is, that the bottom one is in **bold** font weight.